# Many to Many Self Referencing Search

Tags: doctrine-orm, jms-serializer

I have a "**Many to Many Self Referencing**" entity and need to do a **search** for the elements **parents** are **children**.
For example

```
{
    "id": 58,
    "name": "DVD & Home Theater",
    "parent": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "TV & Video",
        "parent": null
    }
}
```

search for "**Home Tv**" where part of the text is in the parent element.
I could add an extra column and when persist the entity concatenate the parent element name in the child "**TV and Video> DVD and Home Theater**" is to use this column to search

I would also like to return an element only where the name of the parent element would be inserted in the child element

```
{
    "id": 58,
    "name": "TV & Video > DVD & Home Theater"
}
```

this assumption problem I was able to solve using the following notation

```
/**
* @JMS\PreSerialize
* @return mixed
*/
public function getParent()
{
    $parent = $this->parent;
    if ($parent) {
        $this->name = $this->parent->getName() . ' > ' . $this->name;
    }
    return $parent;
}
```

I would like to have something like this end result like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "TV e Vídeo"
    }, {
        "id": 59,
        "name": "TV e Vídeo > TV Led"
    }, {
        "id": 82,
        "name": "TV e Vídeo > Antenas"
    }, {
        "id": 58,
        "name": "TV e Vídeo > DVD e Home Theater"
    }
]
```